# Linked Files and Folder in IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, directory

As previous Eclipse user switched to IntelliJ I would like to be able to access folder external to my project from inside the IDE, while developing.

In Eclipse I was using the feature [Creating linked resources](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-45.htm).

I wonder if there is any feature in IntelliJ that helps me to access external files and folder in a similar way (for instance, if I want to edit the configuration of my application server which is located outside my project).

Comment: The link in the question seem outdated. Please update if possible.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes you can do it by adding an new content root in your module.
You do that from 
**Project Structure** (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) - **Modules** - "**My-Module**" - **+ Add Content root** 
[image]

Now you have the contents of the added folder available in your project.

Comment: Perfect. it helped me too. Also for the "create link" in eclipse, I had created symlinks from terminal, in ubuntu "ln -s .."

Comment: There is one restriction with this approach. A directory can only be a root contenf of exactly one module. If you want to access the external sources from multiple modules, this doesn´t work.

Comment: I am using Android studio. I could not find the command "add root content".

Comment: Press SHIFT twice and the write "Project Structure"

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a way to get the asset folder link working in IntelliJ as it was working in Eclipse and I found following link in the wikis of libgdx itself.

[Linking the asset directories](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-intellij-idea#linking-the-asset-directories)

It describes basically three approaches:

1. Just copy the asset folder into the desktop folder. (BAD)
2. Use the asset folder in the android project as working directory for the desktop project through 'Run-Configurations'. (GOOD)
3. Create a symbolic-link (GOOD)

I tested the 2nd option and it's working fine for me.