# How to link external files/folders (eclipse's linkedresources functionality) using gradle in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-5.0-lollipop, eclipse-adt

How to get external files/folders added to assets folder just before build using android studio or gradle? I used to add css files from my web project to the android assets folder in eclipse using linkedresources but after moving to android studio unable to achieve it using gradle. Kindly advice.

Eclipse .project file used to look like this

```
<linkedResources>
    <link>
        <name>css</name>
        <type>2</type>
        <location>C:/Server/Apache/htdocs/project/public/css</location>
    </link>
</linkedResources>
```

What will be the equivalent in the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is an IntelliJ IDE. As such, a lot of the help for IntelliJ is applicable. Here is a question that addresses your issue:

[Linked Files and Folder in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058448/linked-files-and-folder-in-intellij)