# LibGDX TextureAtlas, can't load button.pack

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am having some issues with loading button.pack made in TexturePacker. I really can't find where is the problem. If someone can see it from my GameScreen class please let me know. Thank you very much.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    Stage stage;
    TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;
    TextButtonStyle buttonStyle;
    TextButton button;
    Skin skin;

    SpriteBatch batch;

    private GameWorld world;
    private GameRenderer renderer;
    private float runTime;

    // This is the constructor, not the class declaration
    public GameScreen() {

        float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float gameWidth = 544;
        float gameHeight = screenHeight / (screenWidth / gameWidth);

        world = new GameWorld();
        renderer = new GameRenderer(world, (int) gameHeight, (int) gameWidth);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputHandler(world));
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        runTime += delta;
        world.update(delta);
        renderer.render(runTime);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();

        batch.begin();
        stage.draw();
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        System.out.println("GameScreen - resizing");
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("GameScreen - show called");

        stage = new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),
                true);
        skin = new Skin();
        buttonAtlas = new TextureAtlas("button.pack");
        skin.addRegions(buttonAtlas);

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        System.out.println("GameScreen - hide called");
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        System.out.println("GameScreen - pause called");
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        System.out.println("GameScreen - resume called");
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // Leave blank
    }
}
```

Every time, no matter what change I make, it says "Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: button.pack (Internal)"
I checked in assets folder, button.pack and button.png are there :/

Comment: is the "assets" folder shared with all projects ?

Comment: put your assets in android asset folder? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22833470/1268823

Answer (score 0):

Use AssetManager for your game.
Code:

```
AssetManager am = new AssetManager();
am.load("buttons.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
am.finishLoading();
buttonAtlas = am.get("buttons.pack");
```

Then you can use your atlas.
And don't forget to put your atlas to game-android/assets directory.