# File not found exception using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I've got Gradle projects and 2 IDE's: NetBeans and IntelliJ. NetBeans works perfectly with this project, no errors found.
But IntelliJ in the same project throws exception:

```
[Assets] error: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: ./images/enemy.atlas (Internal)
```

Here is Java class:

```
public class Assets {           
    public static AssetManager assetManager;           
    public Assets() {
        assetManager = new AssetManager();
        try {
            assetManager.load("./images/enemy.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
            assetManager.load("./images/buttons.atlas", TextureAtlas.class);
            assetManager.load("./fonts/000.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
            assetManager.load("./fonts/111.fnt", BitmapFont.class);
            assetManager.setLoader(TiledMap.class, new TmxMapLoader(new InternalFileHandleResolver()));
            assetManager.load("./world/level1/map.tmx", TiledMap.class);
            assetManager.finishLoading();
        } catch (GdxRuntimeException e) { if (Variables.isDebug) System.err.println("\n[Assets] error: " + e + "\n"); }
     } 
}
```

It is simple, right? So, I've looked through *.gradle files and noticed that gradle knows where to search for my assets:

```
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");
```

I've remade project especially for IDEA (using gdx-setup.jar), but same problem arises. I'm confused and asking for advise!

P.S. AssetManager is a class of LibGDX 1.1.0 library.

Comment: Were you able to compile and run the simple "Hello, World!" app that `gdx-setup.jar` creates before adding your own code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["File not found" when running new LibGDX project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822767/file-not-found-when-running-new-libgdx-project)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ommiting the `./` at the beginning of the path? See: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#loading-assets

`./` usually references the current directory, but I don't know how libgdx handles it. I can't post this as a comment somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. After 3 hours of being angry i realized that path is case sensitive.
Example for tile map:

Android assets file structure:
**assets/Maps/Desert.tmx**

```
//Work as desktop luncher but not on android
TiledMap tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps\\Desert.tmx"); 

//Works on android and dektop
TiledMap tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("Maps\\Desert.tmx");
```

Second thing which I noticed is that path shouldn't start with

```
./  
../
.\\
..\\

//Enough
"Maps\\Desert.tmx"

//Too much
".\\Maps\\Desert.tmx"
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way outs for IDEA is to set the `Working directory` for the Desktop run configuration to your `android/assets/` folder.

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell the "desktop module" to look for assets in the "android module." I forget the exact steps to do this...