# Libgdx project Exception in thread "LWJGL Application". Couldn't load file. Error log inside

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I am a newbie in `libgdx` and just got it setup in android studio. Now I am getting this error when I press run for the first time.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java 
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: badlogic1.jpg
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
    at com.TigerBudda.ZombieBird.ZBGame.create(ZBGame.java:16)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: badlogic1.jpg (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:220)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 48):

Are you run Desktop Application?
Make sure you link your desktop assets to android assets folder?

On Eclipse : [New libgdx setup receive file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822767/new-libgdx-setup-receive-file-not-found/22833470#22833470)

Edited:

On Android Studio

Choose **Edit Configuration..** => "Working directory" => Change folder to `android/assets`

[image: Edit Configuration..]
[image: Edit Configuration2]

Comment: Exceptional answer, been looking for this all day.

Answer (score 3):

```
static{
    System.out.println(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath());
}
```

It displayed the path to the project root folder outside the android/desktop specific modules.
Copied to files to a path relative to the root folder of project and it worked.

Project
Project/core
Project/android
Project/desktop
Project/html
Project/android/assets/data/img.png
What worked: Project/data/img.png

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing nvidia-375 driver solved the issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
```

reboot. And then ta-da! It's working.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Tried the previously stated solutions with no luck. I ended up renaming the filename and miraculously it worked.