# How do I link assets from android to desktop in libgdx?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, assets

Whenever I try to run the desktop version of my LibGDX project it says "badlogic.jpg not found". How can I link the assets folder from android to desktop?

I found [this post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1537) but I can't find out how to do it for android studio. I tried just copying the assets folder but that doesn't work.

Comment: Instructions here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA

Comment: Ok thanks that worked. I forgot android studio was basically just intellij.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New libgdx setup receive file not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822767/new-libgdx-setup-receive-file-not-found)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set working directory to path/android/assets when running the desktop launcher

Comment: Specifically, <project>/mobile/src/main/assets (for my somewhat older project.)

Comment: The problem with this is then when I use `Gdx.files.local` it will use the same directory and screw things up.

Answer (score 20):

Click `Run -> Edit configurations...`, then change the "Working directory" parameter. Click "Apply" and run again.

[image]