# Libgdx cant find new TextureAtlas

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm new to libgdx, and I get this exception:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: C:/Users/myname/Desktop/myLibgdxGame/android/assets/sprites.png/sprites.png
```

on the following function on the `textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("sprites.txt");`  line and I can't understand what's wrong.

```
@Override
    public void create() {

        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        textureAtlas = new TextureAtlas("sprites.txt");
        banana = textureAtlas.createSprite("spr");


    }
```

Anyone knows what is the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: See here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822767/new-libgdx-setup-receive-file-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path which you have given for texture atlas is wrong . In your case, Run time exception occurs because the java is unable to locate your texture atlas. So make sure that the texture atlas path is correct.