# Package libgdx game for desktop

Tags: libgdx, software-distribution

I primarily use LibGDX to develop games for Android. It is helpful to test on the desktop. When I do so, I just set the "desktop" project in Android Studio to use the assets from the "android" project, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822767/new-libgdx-setup-receive-file-not-found/25296759#25296759). This works great on my local machine for testing purposes. However, it won't work if I want to package my game and release it for other's to play on their own machines. How do I go about packaging my game to include the graphic and audio assets?

Comment: Here is the official step-by-step guide: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-windowslinuxmac-os-x

Comment: @Rinold Thanks for the link. Looks like it is out of date: "...to create a runnable JAR in Eclipse...".

Comment: Ohh... sorry :( missed that. Other way is to use gradle then, run in command line from your project dir (with build.gradle) - "gradlew desktop:dist"

Comment: @Rinold Thanks. I just found the `dist` task in the `desktop` project. Looks like it includes the `android/assets` directory when it builds the JAR file.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/packr If you want to bundle the JRE to make it into an EXE.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for the link. That is a related, but different, question from what I am asking here.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on the following snippet in the `build.gradle` file:

```
task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}
```

This appears to bundle `project.assetsDir` into the JAR file created by the `dist` task which is set as

```
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");
```

To run the above task from the command line, type

```
gradlew desktop:dist
```