# Load BitmapFont Android LibGdx

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

I am trying to use `BitmapFont` from file `1.ttf` (LibGdx application for android). However wherever I put this file, I obtain an error that it is not found. Here is my code:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("1.ttf"), false);
```

Where should I put this font file? Or what should I change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't create `BitmapFont` directly using `.ttf` file. You need to use [Gdx freetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype) in your project.

Since gdx-freetype is an extension, it is not included in your LibGDX project by default so [put](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype#how-to-put-gdx-freetype-in-your-project) gdx-freetype in your project. If your project using gradle for dependency management, add [required](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#freetypefont-gradle) artifacts in your root `build.gradle` file.

After injection of required dependency, keep your `.ttf` file inside assets folder of android module, that will share with other module using config.

Generate `BitmapFont` using `FreeTypeFontGenerator` in this way :

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("1.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 12;
BitmapFont font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
generator.dispose(); // don't forget to dispose to avoid memory leaks!
```

Comment: The important part that helped me was to put the font or font directory in the "assets" folder AND NOT the "res" folder! thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You should place the file in `android/assets`. To run the desktop version from Android Studio, you will need to modify the run configuration as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25296759/1440565).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hiero gdx tool: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero runnable jar is here: [runnable-hiero](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/runnables/runnable-hiero.jar).

Open this jar, setup font you want and save it as BitmapFont File. You should put it somewhere in `{PROJECT_FOLDER}/android/assets` folder. 
Now, when you have your .fnt font file, you can load BitmapFont as follow:

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("your_font_file.fnt"));
```

Remember to dispose it when you do not need it anymore or when app exit, ex:

```
public class App implements ApplicationListener {
    BitmapFont font;

    //...
    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        font.dispose();
    }
}
```