# LibGdx Defined Skin Error

Tags: libgdx

I am new to using the `Skin` element in LibGdx. My objective is just to perform simple `Skin` usage with changing the default font type of every element. However, it keeps giving me errors.

My main code:

```java
public class SettingWindow{        
    Skin skin;

    public SettingWindow(){
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("UISkin.json"));
    }
}
```

My json code:

```json
{  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: windowText.fnt }}
```

My error:

```sh
 `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UISkin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74)
    at Scene.TimerSettingWindow.<init>(TimerSettingWindow.java:40)
    at Scene.Hud.<init>(Hud.java:62)
    at Screens.MainScreen.<init>(MainScreen.java:42)
    at com.aipetgame.AiPetGame.create(AiPetGame.java:19)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UISkin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:683)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
    ... 7 more           
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: UISkin.json
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:77)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:681)
    ... 8 more           
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: UISkin.json (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:163)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75)
    ... 9 more  `
```

I store everything in android/assets folder. Please help..

( I was trying to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELkqiMpvMLA  )

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["File not found" when running new LibGDX project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822767/file-not-found-when-running-new-libgdx-project)

Comment: Create a new LibGDX project and try to run it. Do you get the same error? If so, see the link above for the fix.

Comment: Will try it and confirm again later. Thanks

Comment: My problem solved by restart the whole android studio, and recreate the json file. Have no clues about the reasons why but will continue my project anyway. Thanks.