# Libgdx: Gdx.files.internal() points to wrong place on laptop, correct place on desktop?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, libgdx

In my Eclipse LibGDX project, it seems to think that the root directory is different between machines. For example, on my desktop, and the desktops of two other friends running the same version of Java and Eclipse with a git-cloned project, running `File file = new File("/config")` returns this path:

```
/core/assets/config
```

Running it with the same version of Eclipse, and the same Java version, and the same git-cloned project, on my laptop, produces the following:

```
/desktop/config
```

Clearly, there is something wrong here. Even the native LibGDX file-handlers are looking for the assets folder in /desktop/ instead of /core/, which is a problem since it completely breaks the otherwise functional code, rendering my laptop completely ineffective for development purposes.

What I have done:

- Reinstalled Java on laptop
- Reinstalled Eclipse, removed all user-preferences on laptop
- Completely deleted directory containing git project

What can I try to resolve this?

If you want to see the structure of the project in question, please see [here](https://github.com/AaronSigal/LibGDX-Practice/tree/test_aaron/Lootly)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822767/6309 might help

Answer (score 1):

Set the working directory to core/assets/ directory when running the application.